# Insertion sort linked list c++

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, insertion-sort

I'm trying to sort a filled linked list with random numbers. The function I have made doesnt work as it should. I can't see what is wrong, its not sorting the numbers properly.

```
void linked_list::SortList()
{
   if(is_empty())
   {
      return;
   }
   for(node_t *it =head; it!=tail; it = it->next)
   {
      int valToIns = it->value;
      node_t *holePos = it;
      while(holePos->prev && valToIns < it->prev->value)
      {
         holePos->value = holePos->prev->value;
         holePos = holePos->prev;
      }
      holePos->value = valToIns;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing with the wrong element,

```
while(holePos->prev && valToIns < it->prev->value)
```

should be

```
while(holePos->prev && valToIns < holePos->prev->value)
```

in order to compare `valToIns` with the value before the one `holePos` points to.